# en/decode MultisigxV2R1 and get raw data / Check if "MultisigxV2R1..." correspond to known address

Tags: viewkey, multisig, spend-key

Is there any way to make it on my own, without using monero-cli?

I'm trying to create a 2-of-2 multisig using raw private keys. not from seed

My example scene are follows. Bob and Alice generate private spend/view key. They will exchange `ViewKeyPair` (priv_view, pub_spend). They need to create a 2-of-2 multisig. The problem is I need to verify that `alice_pub_spend` are used.

In simple word, I need to make sure that the `MultisigxV2R1` given by Alice will be the `public_spend` that she give earlier.

sample code

```
alice_pub_spend = "xxxx"
multisig_r1 = "MultisigxV2R1..."
decoded = decode(multisig_r1)
if decoded.spend == alice_pub_spend:
   ...
```

is there any best method for my problem? aside from "decoding" `MultisigxV2R1` and extract data